# Is there any way to limit access for developers to specific folders in gitlab or github?

Tags: git, github, permissions, gitlab, repository

I have a project on Gitlab and I want to limit my developers to access only specific folders. For example I have 10 folders and I want developer1 to access only 5 folders in one repository and developer2 to access only 2 folders on repository. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, each of those folders are repositories of their own, which you can make private, and add only the relevant developers to each one.

You can then have a parent repository which would reference those [other repositories as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), each one in their own subfolder.

That way, only the approved developers can access the right folders.